# hover on type="text/css" trying to

Tags: html, css

How do I add a hover style to highlight a row that the cursor is on? I am trying to hover just one row of entire the `cell` instead of one `cell`, which is what its doing right now.
here's my `table`

```
<table>
    
    <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Views</th>
    </tr>
        <%  for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { %>
        <tr onclick="location.href='./detail.jsp?bno=<%=list.get(i).getBno()%>'">
            <td><%=list.get(i).getBno()%></td>
            <td id= "Title"><%=list.get(i).getBtitle() %></td>
            <td><%= list.get(i).getName()%></td>
            <td><%= list.get(i).getBdate()%></td>
            <td><%= list.get(i).getBcount()%></td>
            </tr>
        
    <%}%>
    
    </table>
```

and what's on the css

```
tr :hover {bg-color: white;

}
```

Comment: is you tr: hover without no space between tr: and hover, so => `tr:hover` not `tr: hover`?

Comment: you have BAD css key " bg-color ". This should be " background-color " instead. This is typo.

Comment: tr:hover { background-color: red; }  you might as well use red for the mean time so u can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property's name is `background-color` (not `bg-color`), and you have to omit the space between `tr` and `:hover`:

```css
tr:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Views</th>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="location.href='./detail.jsp?bno=<%=list.get(i).getBno()%>'">
    <td>
      <%=list.get(i).getBno()%>
    </td>
    <td id="Title">
      <%=list.get(i).getBtitle() %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= list.get(i).getName()%>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= list.get(i).getBdate()%>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= list.get(i).getBcount()%>
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```